# Format Time Reported by AbsoluteTiming

Tags: date-and-time, units, conversion, timing

I am trying to format the timing reported by `AbsoluteTiming` so that it states the hours minutes and seconds of the result. However, probably because `AbsoluteTiming` has the attribute `HoldAll`, the results are not entirely as I would expect them.

I define the two related functions:

```
secondsToHoursMinutes[secs_] := Module[{
   hrs = Floor[secs/3600],
   mins = Floor[Mod[secs, 3600]/60],
   scs = Mod[secs, 60]},
  If[hrs == 0, "0", ToString[hrs]] <> ":" <> 
   Which[mins == 0, "00", mins < 10, "0" <> ToString[mins], True, 
    ToString[mins]] <> ":" <> 
   Which[scs == 0, "00", scs < 10, "0" <> ToString[scs], True, 
    ToString[scs]]]
absTimingInHoursMinutes[
  operation_] := (({secondsToHoursMinutes[#[[1]]], #[[2]]}) &[
   AbsoluteTiming[operation]])
```

However, the results of the following are different. I have tried putting `Evaluate@` and `ReleaseHold@` inside or around `AbsoluteTiming` to no avail. Any ideas?

```
Table[i, {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
absTimingInHoursMinutes[Table[i, {10^6}];]
Table[i, {10^6}]; // absTimingInHoursMinutes
Table[i, {10^6}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // {secondsToHoursMinutes[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &
{secondsToHoursMinutes[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &[
 AbsoluteTiming[Table[i, {10^6}];]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have these in my kernel init file, my main use case is not wanting to count how many zeroes are in the `AbsoluteTiming` result. Is that milliseconds or microseconds?  I added the `MixedUnit` part here to cover OP's use case.  Hopefully it is useful to someone else.

```
bestUnit[unitLog_] := Which[
    unitLog < -6,
        "Nanoseconds",
    unitLog < -3,
        "Microseconds",
    unitLog < 0,
        "Milliseconds",
    unitLog < 1.77815(*Log10[60.]*),
        "Seconds",
    unitLog < 3.5563(*Log10[60. * 60.]*),
        MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}],
    True,
        MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]
];

fixTime[{t_, res_}] = {
    UnitConvert[Quantity[t, "Seconds"], bestUnit @ Log10 @ t],
    res
};
repeatedTiming[arg__] := fixTime @ RepeatedTiming @ arg;
absoluteTiming[arg__] := fixTime @ AbsoluteTiming @ arg;
Attributes[repeatedTiming] = Attributes @ RepeatedTiming
Attributes[absoluteTiming] = Attributes @ AbsoluteTiming
```

And then use as

```
In[4]:= repeatedTiming[Exp[Range[500]];]

Out[4]= {Quantity[197.414, "Microseconds"], Null}
```

Comment: Ya, I am running a Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo model of a very complex system, where taking many runs to get the precise shape of the underlying distributions can take hours.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add the `HoldFirst` attribute to your timing function, like this

```
SetAttributes[absTimingInHoursMinutes, HoldFirst]
```

Here is my take on a similar function that formats the `AbsoluteTiming` results using the built-in Units & Quantities system.  Without the `HoldFirst` (or `HoldAll`) attribute, this function would not work.

```
ClearAll[absTiming]
SetAttributes[absTiming, HoldFirst]
absTiming[op_] := op // AbsoluteTiming // {UnitConvert[
     Quantity[First[#], "Seconds"],
     MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]], Last[#]} &

SeedRandom[1234]
Eigensystem[RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {14, 14}]]; // absTiming

(*  {0 h 0 min 4.8642s, Null}  *)
```

Comment: Many thanks! Did you intend to have the first word of your answer's third paragraph ("Here") link something?

Comment: @NicholasG  That is good intuition, but, no, I did not intend to link to somewhere else.  I meant "here" as "in this answer".  BTW, thanks for accepting my answer.